# Building a representive sample from a large data set

Tags: distributions, correlation

I have a large data set of parcels (>100k) with the variables length, width, height and weight. 
For simulation purposes I'm only able to use a sample of roughly 10 parcels. To make it as practical as possible I'd like to build a sample that is representative of the whole data set. What is the best way to do this?

I tried to pick random items from the data set but there always seem to be outliers and just shuffling through randomly picked samples until I'm content with the outcome doesn't seem practical. The two-sample KS test however, does give me p-values of >0.2 for each variable.

I thought about building it manually by creating histograms for each variable and then scaling them down to 10 elements but then there is a problem that some of the variables are highly correlated with each other and others not so much. (Kendall's tau gives me values ranging from 0.2 to 0.7)

Edit: Some information about the simulation:
In the course of my bachelor's thesis I have to run a DEM simulation of a separation mechanism of parcels on a conveyor belt. My job is to determine the optimal combination of parameters (with DoE) for a high degree of separation and speed. The computation is very slow, so I can only work with a very limited sample size.

Comment: Have you considered clustering?

Comment: The practical meaning of "representative" in this instance will have to depend on what you are simulating and the purpose of that simulation.  Could you tell us a little about those?

Comment: If you are randomly sampling, the data should be representative (in the ordinary sense of the word), nor could there be any true outliers.

Comment: A friend also just suggested clustering to me. I'm not familiar with cluster analysis so I guess I'll have some reading up to do. 

I edited my question to give some information about the simulation. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the edit (+1). This adds considerable information to the question, because it indicates you are in an *experimental design* situation and that you are seeking to estimate a *response surface* in order to *optimize* a response. That suggests you might *not* want a statistically representative sample--instead, you need one that will give you the best possible estimate of the optimum. If you know nothing about the response, you might want your sample to exhibit a variety of extreme characteristics, whereas if you know about where the optimum is, you want the sample to be near it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I'm not sure I understand though. Just to clarify, the optimum shouldn't be found by adjusting parcel parameters. In reality I have no influence on those. But I don't think that's what your suggesting anyway.
If I understand correctly you suggest I should look for a sample that makes it easiest to determine my optimal system parameters (which include conveyor speed and geometry settings).

Comment: My tutor said not to get hung up on this problem and to just do simulations with a sample of small and big parcels respectively and one with a "representative" sample if I'm able to find one. Hence my original question.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are allowed to pick a limited number, N, of points in the 4-dimensional space, and you need them to cover your region of interest "as evenly as possible". In that case, low discrepancy numbers can help, e.g. try the [Hammersley set described here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence#Hammersley_set)